# How to solve “Notice: Undefined offset”?

Tags: php

this is result of print_r($_POST['select']) :

```
Array
(
    [7_222] => 5
    [7_333] => 4
    [7_444] => 5
    [8_222] => 3
    [8_333] => 5
    [8_444] => 2
    [9_222] => 5
    [9_333] => 3
    [9_444] => 1
)
```

this is my code :

```
    foreach($_POST['select'] as $k => $v) {
    $k=explode('_',$k);
    $row=$k[0];
    $column=$k[1];
    $matrix[$row][$column]=$v;
}
$cb = count($matrix);
$ck = isset($matrix[$row])?count($matrix[$column]):0;

for($row1=0;$row1<$cb;$row1++) {
    for($row2=0;$row2<$cb;$row2++) {
        if($row1!=$row2) {
            echo 'r'.($row1+1).' compared r'.($row2+1).'(r'.($row1+1).($row2+1).') : ';
            $k=array();
            for($column=0;$column<$ck;$column++) {
                if($matrix[$row1][$column]>$matrix[$row2][$column]) {
                    $k[]='k'.($column+1);
                }
            }
            echo implode(',',$k).'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

this is my problem :
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:
........

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the "Related" bar on the right (and start using google **BEFORE** you ask a question here)

Comment: Did you track the line number where error is occurring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549561/notice-undefined-offset-0-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `$matrix` isn't indexed from 0 to X, `print_r($matrix)` gives:

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [222] => 5
            [333] => 4
            [444] => 5
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [222] => 3
... etc ...

)
```

So you actually need your `for($row...` loop to go `7, 8, 9` not `0, 1, 2`. As newman suggested, the easiest way to do this would be to use `foreach`, something like this:

```
foreach($matrix as $row1=>$columns) {
    foreach($matrix as $row2=>$columns2) {
        if($row1!=$row2) {
            echo 'r'.($row1+1).' compared r'.($row2+1).'(r'.($row1+1).($row2+1).') : ';
            $k=array();
            foreach($columns as $column=>$value) {
                if($matrix[$row1][$column]>$matrix[$row2][$column]) {
                    $k[]='k'.($column+1);
                }
            }
            echo implode(',',$k).'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: To include row and column counts as requested. Note we're still using the old values to index the array, but we're also including a count to use in the output:

```
$row1_count= 1;
$row2_count= 1;
$column_count= 1;

foreach($matrix as $row1=>$columns) {
    foreach($matrix as $row2=>$notused) {
        if($row1!=$row2) {
            echo 'r'.($row1_count).' compared r'.($row2_count).'(r'.($row1_count).($row2_count).') : ';
            $k=array();
            foreach($columns as $column=>$value) {
                if($matrix[$row1][$column]>$matrix[$row2][$column]) {
                    $k[]='k'.($column_count);
                }
                $column_count++; // Next column
            }
            $column_count= 1; // Reset the column count
            echo implode(',',$k).'<br>';
        }
        $row2_count++; // Next row
    }
    $row2_count= 1; // Reset the second row count
    $row1_count++; // Next row
}
```

Comment: this result :<br />
r8 compared r9(r89) : k112,k334 <br />
r8 compared r10(r810) : k223,k334<br />
r9 compared r8(r98) : k223<br />
r9 compared r10(r910) : k223,k334<br />
r10 compared r8(r108) :<br />
r10 compared r9(r109) : k112<br />

how to convert the above result to be like this:<br />
r1 compared r2(r12) : k1,k3<br />
r1 compared r3(r13) : k2,k3<br />
r2 compared r1(r21) : k2<br />
r2 compared r3(r23) : k2,k3<br />
r3 compared r1(r31) :<br />
r3 compared r2(r32) : k1<br />

please, help me.

Comment: Assuming you can't rely on the row numbers always being sequential the easiest way would probably be to have a counter inside each of the `foreach` loops and use that in your output.

Comment: I am still confused.
Can you edit the above code so the code looks like this : r1 compared r2(r12) : k1,k3<br />
r1 compared r3(r13) : k2,k3<br />
r2 compared r1(r21) : k2<br />
r2 compared r3(r23) : k2,k3<br />
r3 compared r1(r31) :<br />
r3 compared r2(r32) : k1<br />

Answer (score 0):

In first foreach you fill $matrix and use indexes: 7,8,9

In second script you try access to this array by index from 0