# Noticed : undefined offset: 0 Line 36

Tags: php

Error
**Noticed : undefined offset: 0 Line 37**

Line 37

```
$table = (table2)["response"]["players"][0];
```

Small Cut

```
    ");
}

$steamid64 = $_GET["steamid"];

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $SteamAPIKey . "&steamids=" . $steamid64;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$table2 = json_decode($json, true);
//Undefined Variable which means it hasn't been Verified.
$table = $table2["response"]["players"][0];
print_r($table2);

?>
```

Comment: Clearly there are no elements in the `"players"` collection.  The code assumes there are.  Hence the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549561/notice-undefined-offset-0-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can use print_r($table2); to see how $tables is structured before you get the first item of players.

For example:
Replace

```
$table = $table2["response"]["players"][0];
print_r($table2);
```

By

```
print_r($table2);
$table = $table2["response"]["players"][0];
```