# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 fixable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a "get first image script" I am using that is all over the internet but am getting the error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0

the script is:

```
function get_first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',$post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
return $first_img;
}
```

can this be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549561/notice-undefined-offset-0-in)

Comment: Use `print_r($matches);` to see what matches are available. Use `isset()` or `empty()` to first check it's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your regex this could happen if the `<img>` tag has no src attribute or if there are no `<img>` tags at all.

As others have suggested you *could* fix this by checking `$matches` first, but I'd like to suggest an alternate approach that may be more robust for parsing html in php, since **[using regex to do this is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1767412)**.

```
function get_first_image() {
    global $post;
    $first_img = '';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($post->post_content);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        if ($img->hasAttribute('src')) {
            $first_image = $img->getAttribute('src');
            break;
        }
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

The above function uses php's [DOMDocument Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to iterate over `<img>` tags and get the src attribute if it exists.  (*Note: I removed the `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` functions from your code because I don't understand what purpose they were serving*)

Answer (score 0):

Before operator:

```
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
```

insert the line:

```
var_dump($matches);
```

Make sure, that $matches is an array, and has two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$first_img = isset($matches[1][0]) ? $matches[1][0] : false;
```

Which will, then, return false if the first position in this two dimension array would not exist.