# In Laravel "Undefined offset: 0"

Tags: laravel, pagination

In Laravel view Undefined offset: 0

I got problem before says

> expecting array in parameter 1 but object given

and fix it through `->toArray`. And then appeared this problem

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(3)->toArray();

        return view ('inventory.layout', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }
```

And this is to show my products in view file
I've tried to replace the 0 key with `['data']` string but useless.

```
  @if (isset($products)) 
        @if ($arrkeys = array_keys($products[0])) 
            @foreach ($arrkeys as $key)  
                <th>{{$key}}</th>
            @endforeach
        @endif 
   @endif
```

Comment: in the controller, before you return the view, dump the contents of $products using `dd($products);` and see what is actually being returned by the function call.

Comment: I've already did this and showing me an three paginated array but when i want to display it in view, displaying this error "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Can you show us the response structure so we can compare it against the code you've written in the view and check what might be the issue

Comment: sure:    array:12 [▼
  "current_page" => 1
  "data" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:29 [▶]
    1 => array:29 [▶]
    2 => array:29 [▶]
  ]
  "first_page_url" => "http://localhost:8080/Import-CSV-Laravel/public/layout?page=1"
  "from" => 1
  "last_page" => 10
  "last_page_url" => "http://localhost:8080/Import-CSV-Laravel/public/layout?page=10"
  "next_page_url" => "http://localhost:8080/Import-CSV-Laravel/public/layout?page=2"
  "path" => "http://localhost:8080/Import-CSV-Laravel/public/layout"
  "per_page" => 3
  "prev_page_url" => null
  "to" => 3
  "total" => 30
]

Comment: array:12 [▼
  "current_page" => 1
  "data" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:29 [▶]
    1 => array:29 [▶]
    2 => array:29 [▶]
  ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549561/notice-undefined-offset-0-in)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display pagination use code like this

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(3);

        return view ('inventory.layout', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }



And this is to show my products in view file
I've tried to replace the 0 key with ['data'] string but useless.



  @if (isset($products)) 
           @foreach ($products as $key)  
                <th>{{$key}}</th>
            @endforeach
    //for pagination
    <div>{{$products->links()}}</div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the **keys** of the array, try this:

```
  @if (isset($products))
      @foreach ($products as $key => $value)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
      @endforeach
  @endif
```

But If you want to display the **values**:

```
  @if (isset($products))
      @foreach ($products as $key => $value)  
            <th>{{$value}}</th>
      @endforeach
  @endif
```